# click on a link to scroll to a particular div (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i click a link and try to scroll to a particular div with slow animation the whole page get scrolled instead of that particular div.
I am sharing the link to the plnkr below open it in full screen mode.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5ZlY7ivJ2xwckVeyIRzO?p=preview

for full screen loading

http://run.plnkr.co/HV426GUKePHeJPfS/

The problem is that when the content present in the right hand side panel is clicked (only recommendation and cme & Attended is to cliked) the middle-panel should be scrolled to show that particular div on the top.
Instead what's happening is the whole page is getting scrolled thus making the UI not much of use.
I have tried using the following two javascript code for showing some animation and scrolling the middle_profile  div or mm div but none of them is working.

for scrolling middle_profile div

```
$("#bb").click(function() {
  $('.middle_profile').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#recommendationDiv").position().top
  }, 'slow');
});
$("#bb1").click(function() {
  $('.middle_profile').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#CMEDiv").offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

for scrolling mm div

```
var scrolled = 0;
$("#bb").on("click", function() {
  scrolled = scrolled - 300;
  $(".mm").animate({
    scrollTop: scrolled
  }, 50);
});
```

Is there another way of doing it through jquery or some other library is to be included for smooth scrolling the page?

Comment: Please update your snippet with full code what you done.

Comment: you need to animate the html & body here while keeping menu links floating I think

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put inside the $(document).ready() your code, and set in your css the position: relative; top:0; to your div who will be focus.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#bb").click(function() {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#recommendationDiv").offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    });
    $("#bb1").click(function() {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#CMEDiv").offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    });    
    // var scrolled = 0;
    //   $("#bb").on("click" ,function(){
    //      scrolled=scrolled-300;
    //         $(".mm").animate({
    //           scrollTop:  scrolled
    //      },50);
    //    });
  })
```

Comment: it does not help because the whole page it getting scrolled up. where as only the middle division should scroll while keeping the scroll of the other two division steady